# 2sxc Knowledge Management solution hurdles

Tags: permissions, 2sxc

I'm evaluating 2sxc as a possible platform for implementing a knowledge management solution but we're in a bit of a rush. Our alternative is DNN Live Articles.

So far I really like the look of 2sxc, but I have questions regarding our possible use of it.

The main questions I have are around hierarchical lists like nested Categories and permissions.

From the look of some of the apps I've installed like FAQs with Categories but I can't find anything yet where they are nested. I tried creating a Content Type and adding fields where the first is the Category Name and the second is Parent Category. I created a new Content Type Field with a Data Type of Entity, but the only option for Input Type is default and Content Block Items. It works but when you create a new category the content that comes up in the Parent Category field covers just about everything - not sure I understand the concept behind this.

Then the second issue is permissions. Does this system somehow incorporate permissions because we'd like to lock down knowledge articles by category, but I haven't seen any implementations that showcase how one would do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding #1 I don't understand your question, sorry :)

Regarding #2: there is no rule-based security, so you can't say "items with category X may be edited, but category Y may not"
BUT: you can easily implement this in your UI, if your main concern is user guidance and not "bad people with very good IT skills"

Comment: thanks Danniel we've opted to go for Live Articles for the moment but we're certainly going to be looking into 2sxc for future implementations.